# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre una DTO y una entity?

Tags: java, arquitectura-de-software

Me gustaría saber cual es la diferencia entre las dos

Answer (score -1):

Pues no se si estoy en lo correcto, pero tengo entendido que la Entity es para manipulacion de datos, pues son clases que mapean una tabla de una base de datos, sin embargo un DTO, su mismo nombre lo indica, es solo para transporte de datos...
Digamos, quieres consultar la info de un usuario, la Entity te ayudaria a poder consultarlo en la base de datos y el DTO te ayudaria a poder "guardar en memoria" esa informacion que has podido obtener, para poder manipularla a tu gusto...